# Where do screensavers come from in Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screensaver

How can I add a screensaver to my system? I don't want to import an existing one, but to know the mechanics of how to CREATE one from scratch and install it as if it were one of the default ones.

Comment: you should include "create" in the question title.

Answer (score 4):

okay, had to do some research on this one.
first of all, in my distro (ubuntu 10.04 LTS), the screensaver files are .desktop. they are stored in /usr/share/applications/screensavers

if you open them, they are really a config file. this config file leads to an executable program. if you write the program and configure the .desktop, it should work, but I'm not sure.

it actually uses the xscreensaver package, and here's the FAQ on that: http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html